# how to implement sslsocketfactory in android 11

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, retrofit

Android app is properly working with other all API versions, but from android 11 devices
app getting crash. Iam using SSL pinning when API calling with retrofit 2.9.0 and getting following error ;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on AndroidPlatform, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl